# Draw intersection between planes

Tags: tkz-euclide

How can I make the intersection between two planes such that at this intersection we see the two planes, not one above the other.

This is my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\tkzDefPoint(-6,3){A}
\tkzDefPoint(11,4){B}
\tkzDefPoint(15,0){C}`
\tkzDefPoint(-2,-1){D}
\tkzDefPoint(4.56,12.06){E}
\tkzDefPoint(7.14,-2.08){F}
\tkzDefPoint(3,-6){G}
\tkzDefPoint(0.42,8.14){H}
\tkzDrawPolygon[color=red!50,lower left=red!50, upper right=red!50,shade](A,B,C,D)
\tkzDrawPolygon[color=red!50,lower left=red!50, upper right=red!50,shade](E,F,G,H)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Sorry for my English, but my native idiom is Spanish.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet compilable!

Comment: Sorry, but when I wrote the code, I forgot to write down point E. I edited it, now it runs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `clip` within a `scope`.

I've used different colors to better show the intersection but, of course, you can draw both planes in red.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\tikzset{%
    planhor/.style = {color=green!50,lower left=green!50, upper right=green!50,shade},
    planvert/.style = {color=red!50,lower left=red!50, upper right=red!50,shade},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
        \tkzDefPoint(-6,3){A}
        \tkzDefPoint(11,4){B}
        \tkzDefPoint(15,0){C}`
        \tkzDefPoint(-2,-1){D}
        \tkzDefPoint(4.56,12.06){E}
        \tkzDefPoint(7.14,-2.08){F}
        \tkzDefPoint(3,-6){G}
        \tkzDefPoint(0.42,8.14){H}
        \tkzDrawPolygon[planhor](A,B,C,D)
        \tkzDrawPolygon[planvert](E,F,G,H)
        \tkzInterLL(H,G)(A,B) \tkzGetPoint{X}
        \tkzInterLL(F,E)(D,C) \tkzGetPoint{Y}
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (X) -- (A) -- (D) -- (Y);
            \tkzDrawPolygon[planhor](A,B,C,D)
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I did not know the scope command. I like that it stays with different colors.

Comment: @esteban i think the question is well answered so you could vote up and accept Thema question to mark the question as solved.(thats the way to say thank you here)